# Meaning of the word "bat" in the following context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I found this sentence in the short story Two Legs for the Two of Us by James Jones. The larger context is: "George was standing in the door (...) He opened the screen (...) He grinned down at her belligerently through the dark circles and loose lips of an extended **bat**." What could the word "bat" mean here? None of the usual definitions listed in dictionaries seem to fit this context.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's referring to some sort of a canvas flap or some such -- likely a localized term, and very likely something that most would spell as "batt".

Comment: Do you have a link to the full text? (Rathony seems to!)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK You can google "He grinned down at her belligerently through the dark circles and loose lips of an extended bat." and will find the full text.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. It got me back here. EDIT - It works if I omit the quote marks.

Comment: In context, both characters are in the same room at that point. Could it be the *bat* of eyelids?

Comment: I can only imagine that the author is trying to evoke the image of the small flying mammal which often has a strange face. It is not a very comprehensible sentence because I don't usual think of such an animal as having loose lips. So don't waste your time on trying to understand something that isn't coherent.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a baseball metaphor.

> bat = a turn at batting ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bat))

The author is using *extended bat* as a euphemism for a long bout of heavy drinking, the effects of which Sandy can see in George's face.

Comment: That's a clever idea. In fact it is very close to "an extended bout (of drinking)"   https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=bout+of+drinking

Comment: http://dare.wisc.edu/survey-results/1965-1970/tobacco-liquor/dd16